# How do I fix this '<=' is not a prefix unary operator error?

Tags: swift

I am getting error in the "if-else" section.

I am doing Swift in playgrounds.

```
let namescore = arc4random_uniform(101)

if  namescore > 51{
    return "high match of \(namescore)"
} else if  (namescore, >=40 && namescore, <=40) {
    return "avg match of \(namescore)"
}
```

> error:'<=' is not a prefix unary operator
>   error:'>=' is not a prefix unary operator

Comment: You should remove the comma before the operator.

Comment: Your `else if` makes no sense. Once you remove the commas, it will only be true if `namescore` is exactly equal to 40.

Answer (score 2):

The "=" right next to the "40" is confusing Swift (and I think you used "Fix" which added the commas).  Here's a functioning version of your code:

```
import Foundation

func getScore() -> String {
    let namescore = arc4random_uniform(101)

    if namescore > 51 {
        return "high match of \(namescore)"
    } else if (namescore >= 40 && namescore <= 40) {
        return "avg match of \(namescore)"
    } else {
        return "whatever"
    }
}

getScore()
```

Your comparisons to 40 can be simplified to a direct equality comparison.

```
import Foundation

func getScore() -> String {
    let namescore = arc4random_uniform(101)

    if namescore > 51 {
        return "high match of \(namescore)"
    } else if namescore == 40 {
        return "avg match of \(namescore)"
    } else {
        return "whatever"
    }
}

getScore()
```

Comment: I suspect the check should be `if namescore >= 40 {`.